# Paypal Buy Now button is forcing clients to have a Paypal account

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to create a Paypal `Buy Now` button. I want clients to be able to pay with their debit/credit card in case they don't have a Paypal account.

I'm able to achieve this only if I set an amount higher then USD 33.

For example if the amount is higher then $33 I get a `Pay with a Debit or credit card` button
[image]

If I set the amount under $33 I get a `Create an Account` button
[image]

Do you know why is happening this?

Answer (score 0):

Payments Standard is based on browser cookies.  It doesn't have anything to do with the amount.  If you want to force the Credit/Debit card option at all times you'll need to switch to the Express Checkout APIs instead of PayPal Standard buttons.  It will allow you to set parameters so that the guest checkout experience is always available regardless of any browser cookies / cache.

Comment: Unclear. Which browser cookies? Do you mean browser cookies that indicate the user has a PayPal account?

Comment: I've tried within a private window without any cookies set

Comment: The client browser cookies.  Typically if the browser in use has ever logged in to a PayPal account before it will assume that's what you'll be again, so it wouldn't make the guest checkout functionality as prominent.  The point is that you don't have control over that particular feature.  With Express Checkout you would.